# Overlapping Border is neither Silhoutte nor Edge Mark

Tags: rendering, freestyle

I want to separate my spherelike object with a freestyle line. I have added an edge mark.

[image]

At an unfortunate angle the freestyle edge mark seems to be occluded, but creating the silhoutte of overlapping geometry. I don't understand this, how can I create a separation as in the left and right examples which is visible from all angles.

[image]

[image]

As pointed out by Mr Zak, I'm am not using any crease. It's just the edge mark and a subdivision modifier (which I also tried applying before rendering).

Comment: I'd suggest just adding an edge loop next to the creased edge (or beveling the creased edge but removing crease from the beveled edge) to make engine pick those areas easier. This seems like a bug in Fresstyle, same as too few geometry making freestyle lines intersecting each other

Comment: @MrZ Thank you very much for your suggestion. I have gotten a little bit more of the intersecting line, It doesn't disappear completely anymore. I have updated the images and files.

Comment: I mainly meant [using an edge loop between the smooth sphere surface and extrusion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhqSt.jpg) so that freestyle edge doesn't sit next to extruded face loop. It will provide some artifacts (this time from other views) but not apparent ones

Comment: @MrZ I guess this produces acceptable results. I can easily surround my freestyle edges with additional loops to reduce challenging angles. Add an answer if you want?

Comment: Go ahead and add yours, that will be better as you know what limitations are acceptable for you and what worked in the end